# SSIS Package only executes when windows account logged into server

Tags: mysql, ssis, sql-server-2012

This one is giving me a headache.

I have created some SSIS packages in Visual Studio 2015 with the following settings;

domain/user as 
Project Protection Level: EncryptSensitiveWithPassword (password is same as domain/user)
Package Protection Level: EncryptSensitiveWithPassword (password is same as domain/user)

ODBC Connection is tested and working.

SSIS is from SQL Server 2014 => MySQL 5.6, both the 64 and 32 bit ODBC drivers are installed on the Windows Server 2012 box for MySQL.

Deployed package to Integration Service Catalogs.

When I run the package it works 100%, no errors.  But only when the AD account domain/user is logged into the Windows Server 2012 box that the SQL Server is implemented on.

When the domain/user is not logged in the package fails with the following error:

```
Package: Error: An ODBC error -1 has occurred.
Data Flow Task: Error. ODBC Destination failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005
Data Flow Task: Error: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager DATA_WH.root failed with error code 0xC0014009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
```

On SQL Server:

Created Security..Logins..domain/user
Assigned serveradmin role
Mapped to SSISDB and msdb
Status is granted permission to connect to database
Login is enabled
Created credential called database_credential
identity: domain/user
password: same as domain/user
Mapped domain/user to a  database_credential

In SSIS job activity the job is set to run as database_credential as type SQL Server Integration Services Package.

As long as I am logged in as domain/user on the Windows Server, doesn't even need to be logged in to SQL Server the SSIS package runs perfectly.  When the user isn't logged in it falls over.

This is really confusing me.  I'm turning in circles and need some help.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked 32-bit/64-bit? Run job with flag "run as 32-bit" set and post the results.

Comment: @Ferdipux Thanks, tried that in the configuration of the job on SQL Server but still fails.  Even tried by setting the package to 32bit in Debugging properties in Visual Studio, no luck...  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm tempted to just completely ignore SQL SSIS and just run it from a vbs script and invoke the DTEXEC from the command line, I have another package that I run that way and it runs like clockwork.  For some reason the SSIS is giving me headaches.  But the downside to that is I don't get the history etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this, or having the same issue, I implemented a workaround by creating a scheduled task in the windows task scheduler that ran the package using DTEXEC.exe from the command line.

It worked perfectly, the only issue is there is no history as you would normally get using the SSIS service in SQL Server, but on the upside it works regardless of the user being logged in or not.

Hope someone finds this useful.